# Adobe Target, placing user in experience based on URL contains

Tags: adobe, target, segment

If I have an Adobe Target experience that shows content in Experience A to 50% of users and content in Experience B to the other 50% of users...how can I insert someone into one of these two experiences?

I was thinking of having a button the user can click that has a url parameter added to it for example ?exp1, and then a different button that would have ?exp2.

But if I use the refinement 'url contains exp1 or exp2' in each of the experiences in target, then that is only when the mbox will fire. Whereas I want them to fire on the original page that the mbox is on.

Any help is greatly appreciated...thank you all!

Comment: ***THIS HAS BEEN SOLVED

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Target will serve up your two experiences without having a user click a button. You can have experience A hard coded on your site. Then when you go to make your Target A/B test just enter the URL in the first pop-up box that asks for the activity URL.

Then on the next page Experience, A should be what was hard coded and live on your site. Select experience B and code up your second experience. When done you will select your audience - most likely all visitors and then make sure your set to 50/50 split.

This was a visitor will automatically be shown either A or B when they come to your site. The target mbox fires when the page loads and makes the decision who to show what to automatically. One interesting quirk with Adobe Target is that they don't send one customer to A then the next to B and the next to A as you may expect. Sometimes they send a bunch to A back to back before sending some to B. It works out to a 50/50 over time. And the first 24 hours of data may look a little funky as there is sometimes a latency in data being processed. Hope this help.